# How to bind Datatables.net colvisGroup to an external button?

Tags: jquery, css, html, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to create a show/hide column group using colvisGroup exactly like this example.

https://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/columnGroups.html

I'm satisfied with the functionality but can't bind it to an external button. I need to bind it to external buttons. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bind the actions to different buttons? Seems more practical to move the generated buttons to another container. You could for example do this in the `initComplete` callback.

Move the entire buttons section to another container

```
initComplete: function() {
  $('.dt-buttons').detach().appendTo('#container')
}
```

Move `colvisGroup` buttons only to another container (as the linked-to example from the docs) :

```
$('.dt-button.buttons-colvisGroup').each(function() {
   $(this).detach().appendTo('#container')
})
```